# Uniqueness of an orthogonal vector between a given point and a given subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional vector $b = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}$ and an $m$-dimensional vector subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$.

How to prove that there exists only one vector from $b$ to $V$ orthogonal to $V$? I mean how to show that there is no two vectors starting at $b$ and ending at $V$ that are orthogonal to $V$?

It's visually obvious for 2D and 3D, but how do we know that's true for higher dimensional spaces?

---

I also recall that in school we proved the fact that there is only one perpendicular between a given point and a given line. Is there a similar prove for general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be a basis for the subspace $V$.  Then

$b = B u + b_0 $

where $u \in \mathbb{R}^m $

If $b_0$ is orthogonal to $V$ then it is orthogonal to all the column vectors of matrix $B$, i.e. $B^T b_0 = 0 $

Now, premultiplying by $B^T$

$B^T b = B^T B u + B^T b_0 = B^T B u $

Since $B$ has full rank of $m$, then $B^T B$ is invertible, and

$u = (B^T B)^{-1} B^T b $

From which

$b_0 = b - B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T b = (I - B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T ) b $

The above steps show that there is only one vector $b_0$ that is orthogonal to $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much!